# Issues with processing apostrophe in SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, sql, encryption

I have a `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` object which uses `ComputeHash` method to create a password:

```
private static byte[] GetSHA1(string userLogin, string userPassword)
{
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    return sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userLogin + userPassword));
}
```

I then get byte[20] object holding my encrypted password. I save it to the database using SqlCommand with parameters:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrPassword", securePassword);
```

And paste @usrPassword parameter into SQL INSERT query.

When user logs into the system I retrieve the `byte[20]` object from the database and compare it with the values provided in login form. And everything works fine, unless user creates login with apostrophe while registering (like O'Hara). For some strange reason database stores these passwords in `byte[4]` form, so they do not pass the comparison and user cannot log in.

It looks to me like `SqlCommand` cuts off part of the byte[] object whenever it saves user with apostrophe in name, because `securePassword` variable while registering is represented by byte[20], but whenever the same data is retrieved from database its byte[4].

I use SQL Express 2008, and Password field is of `varbinary(20)` type.

Comment: I think it's *far* more likely that something else in your system is performing some sort of "safety" filtering. Don't forget that the value returned by `GetSHA1` is just a byte array - it's got no knowledge of whether the password originally contained an apostrophe. You should perform a thorough diagnosis of where the data is going missing, right through your stack.

Comment: Hi, up to the level of this statement: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrPassword", securePassword); it seems to be fine. I source my password using SqlDataReader hashedPassword = (Byte[])reader["usrPassword"]; and this is when it appears as byte[4], but as I mention only the one where user login had apsotrophe in it

Comment: Well have you looked at what's actually in the database? What does your query look like?

Comment: Use reader.GetBytes() you can't cast it to a byte array.

Comment: Sorry I have just found a bug in my code causing that. Thanks vary much for help any way.

Comment: As a side-note: Using SHA-1 for password hashing is a really bad idea. Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt with a salt and sufficient iterations. And don't use ASCII, that silently corrupts non-ASCII passwords and usernames. Use UTF-8.